# How to transfer all filters and exceptions from Adblock Plus to uBlock?

Tags: firefox, firefox-extensions, adblock

I have collected a bunch of filters, both subscriptions and custom, and set a lot of exceptions and specific rules on ABP on my Firefox. Trying out uBlock, Is there a way to cleanly transfer all those filters and exceptions without manually having to set each individual filter and exception manually again?

Adding subscriptions is easy enough, because uBlock has a tab specifically for adding subscriptions, but that doesn't include the custom filters/exceptions I've accumulated.

I'm aware that ABP has this "Create new Backup" feature which I might be able to assume can be used to move the filters to uBlock. Will copy-pasting that created backup to uBlock's "My Filters" tab apply every filter rule and exception from ABP or is there a different way to use it? That "My Filters" tab mentioned that a filter can be an "Adblock Plus-compatible filter" but does the ABP backup need some formatting for uBlock to be able to apply it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add your subscriptions to the `3rd-party filters` tab, and copy and paste your custom filters to the `My filters` tab.

You may also be interested in learning [how to use dynamic rules](https://github.com/gorhill/uBlock/wiki/Dynamic-filtering:-rule-syntax) to create new filters faster.

Comment: I know that I can add the subscription URLs there. What I'm asking is how to add ALL the filters including my own added custom ones and exceptions (basically, including the "Custom Filters" tab in ABP's settings).

Comment: I've already answered your question. All custom filters go to the My filters tab.

Comment: My mistake. Somehow missed that last part. Does that mean directly copy-pasting the contents of the ABP backup file?

Comment: I believe that I copied them directly from the ABP options window, but you can try using the backup file too.

Comment: Copied sections from the backup and it worked.

Comment: This is a good example of bad UI design. It’s completely impossible to know that one can call the copy command from that window, since that’s only a thing with text and with files in a file manager, unless you do it by random accident or somebody told you. And since you don’t know it exists, you obviously won’t be able to think of googling for it either. Thank you, Apple! You made the world believe that this was acceptable design!